# riched32.dll or riched20.dll sourcode

Tags: richedit

Is the sourcecode of riched32.dll or riched20.dll available somewhere

If not - what could I do if i want to create a richedit textfield that behaves slightly different (like changing the control for the scrollbars, such that i can change the size and positions of them from outside)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, if one wants to create a common control that behaves differently, they would create it as usual and **[subclass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997565.aspx)** it.

Comment: hey!

thanks i have already read about sub and super classing. but how would i extend it by subclassing such that i can actually change the logics of the control?
let's say i want to be able to display two carets instead of only one. or that the textfield scrolls up if i move the scrollbar upwards (instead of wise versa)

how can i do such things?

Comment: There can only be one caret, but you can emulate a second caret by hadling WM_PAINT in your subclass routine and drawing that caret on your own. Similarly, you can reverse the scrollbars logic by intercepting WM_VSCROLL and changing it's parameters before calling DefWindowProc.

Comment: Thanks!
Do you know any good tutorials that cover stuff like that?